# Plotting data only from February 1, 2021 to March 15, 2021 without removing data before February

Tags: python, pandas

Let me write down what I have done so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 19)
end = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 15)

KE = web.DataReader("BEKE", "yahoo", start, end)

ma5 = KE['Adj Close'].rolling(window=5).mean()
ma20 = KE['Adj Close'].rolling(window=20).mean()
ma60 = KE['Adj Close'].rolling(window=60).mean()
ma120 = KE['Adj Close'].rolling(window=120).mean()

plt.style.use('classic')

KE.insert(len(KE.columns), "MA5", ma5)
KE.insert(len(KE.columns), "MA20", ma20)
KE.insert(len(KE.columns), "MA60", ma60)
KE.insert(len(KE.columns), "MA120", ma120)

plt.plot(KE.index, KE['Adj Close'], label="Adj Close",)
plt.plot(KE.index, KE['MA5'], label="MA5")
plt.plot(KE.index, KE['MA20'], label="MA20")
plt.plot(KE.index, KE['MA60'], label="MA60")
plt.plot(KE.index, KE['MA120'], label="MA120")

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I only need to plot the data from February 1, 2021 to March 15, 2021.

I don't want to remove the data series before February because the line MA60 and MA120 cannot be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a subset of the DataFrame using `.loc` like this:

```
# KE.insert(len(KE.columns), "MA5", ma5)
# KE.insert(len(KE.columns), "MA20", ma20)
# KE.insert(len(KE.columns), "MA60", ma60)
# KE.insert(len(KE.columns), "MA120", ma120)
# above lines shown to indicate where to add the following line:
KE_subset = KE.loc[datetime.date(2021,2,1):datetime.date(2021,3,15)]
```

And then you'd just plot that subset instead of the full DataFrame:

```
plt.plot(KE_subset.index, KE_subset['Adj Close'], label="Adj Close",) 
plt.plot(KE_subset.index, KE_subset['MA5'], label="MA5") 
plt.plot(KE_subset.index, KE_subset['MA20'], label="MA20") 
plt.plot(KE_subset.index, KE_subset['MA60'], label="MA60") 
plt.plot(KE_subset.index, KE_subset['MA120'], label="MA120")

# I also rotated the x-axis labels to fit better with:
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!
It helped a lot!!